# What is wrong with this SQL query to display certain items based on results from a prior query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to display a list of cars which are available at the current time. I made a huge query for what I expected to do the job but its not displaying any cars and if i use `var_dump()` to output the value of `$available` its giving me this output:

> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["car_car_id"]=> string(1) "1" }

The output of the code below is that it echos the `test` string literal 3 times.

What is wrong with the SQL?

```
  <?php
            $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT car_car_id FROM invoice_line WHERE '2017-06-12' > start_date AND '2017-06-12' < end_date OR '2017-06-12' > start_date AND '2017-06-14' < start_date OR '2017-06-12' < start_date AND '2017-06-14' > end_date OR '2017-06-12' != start_date OR '2017-06-14' != end_date OR '2017-06-12' != end_date OR '2017-06-14' != start_date");
            $available = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $product_array= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM car WHERE id != '$available'");
            while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($product_array)){
              echo 'test';
            }
            if (!empty($product_array)) {
              foreach($product_array as $key=>$value){
            ?>
              <div class="product-item">
                <form method="post" action="cars.php?action=add&code=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["id"]; ?>">
                <div><strong><?php echo $product_array[$key]["brand"]; ?> <?php echo $product_array[$key]["type"]; ?></strong></div>
                <div class="product-price"><?php echo "€".$product_array[$key]["price"]; ?></div>
                <div><input type="submit" value="toevoegen aan winkelwagen" class="btnAddAction" /></div>
                </form>
              </div>
            <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
```

[image: expected table output]

Comment: Try segregating your `OR` and `AND` conditions with brackets. Something like `(A AND B) OR (C AND D)` rather than `A AND B OR C AND D`.

Comment: is the image the expected results of the first query or all records in the table?

Comment: @SamOnela its an example of how the table looks like expected should be only displaying car_car_id 1 since number 3 is rented in the period 2017-06-12 till 2017-06-14

Comment: is `mysqli_result` a function defined in your code? or is the first line trying to instantiate a new instance of the [mysqli_result](http://php.net/mysqli_result) class? (e.g. like the function in [this note](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php#109782)?)

Comment: @SamOnela i just added the exect code from the note and now im getting a string(1) "1" in the var_dump

Comment: That doesn't really answer [the question in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530391/display-only-the-available-items?noredirect=1#comment76053543_44530391)...

Comment: he is probably trying to run mysqli_result class. Marijn do you mind to change a bit the structure of the kenteken variable and let me know what the result is? $sql = "your query here";
$result = mysqli_query($sql,$con);

echo mysqli_result($result,0);

Comment: @mele sorry for not replying had some issue's with internet connection however i changed my code while being offline and its shown above here, I'll go home now and let you know the result of your structure.

Comment: @SamOnela sorry but i was indeed trying the  mysqli_result class

Comment: Is the output of `var_dump($available)` really _empty_ or is it the output you quoted: `array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["car_car_id"]=> string(1) "1" }` ??

Comment: @SamOnela made a mistake its not empty but the quoted part, changing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Tl;dr:

Use `NOT IN ()` in the second SQL query instead of `id != '$available'`, and separate the values of the array (e.g. using [implode()](http://php.net/implode)).

#### Your question

> Whats wrong with the sql?

The biggest noticeable issue is that the second query puts the array returned from fetching the array from the first query directly into the second query. This line:

```
$product_array= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM car WHERE id != '$available'");
```

when substituting `$available` could be conceptualized as:

```
$product_array= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM car WHERE id != 'Array'");
```

Presumably the desired condition is that the *id* field of the **car** table does not equal any value in the array of car ids (from the first query). In SQL we could use the [IN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator, combined with *NOT*. For example:

```
WHERE id NOT IN (3,4)
```

There are multiple techniques for generating this with PHP. One is to use [implode()](http://php.net/implode) to create a comma separated string:

```
$available = array('car_car_id' => 3, 'car_car_id' => 4); //Sample
$ids = implode(', ', $available); //3,4 when $available has those elements
$product_array= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM car WHERE id NOT IN ($ids)");
```

#### Duplicated values

You may notice that the IDs are duplicated:

> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["car_car_id"]=> string(1) "1" }

That comes because there is no (2<sup>nd</sup>) argument for [$resulttype](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-array-parameters) passed to [mysql_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) and the default is *MYSQLI_BOTH*:

```
$available = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

To only select the name of the column, use *MYSQLI_ASSOC*

```
$available = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
// => Array ( [car_car_id] => 1 )
```

Or for numeric indexes only, use MYSQLI_NUM

```
$available = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
// => Array ( [0] => 1 )
```

#### First query- operators in WHERE clause

As [Yusef Hassan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7313217/yusuf-hassan) mentioned in [the first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530391/display-only-the-available-items/44550482#comment76052798_44530391), there needs to be consideration for the conditions. Bear in mind that *AND* has higher precedence over *OR* (refer to [MySQL Operator Precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)).

There is a big difference between:

```
SELECT car_car_id 
FROM invoice_line 
WHERE '2017-06-12' > start_date AND '2017-06-12' < end_date
 OR '2017-06-12' > start_date AND '2017-06-14' < start_date 
 OR '2017-06-12' < start_date AND '2017-06-14' > end_date 
 OR '2017-06-12' != start_date OR '2017-06-14' != end_date 
 OR '2017-06-12' != end_date OR '2017-06-14' != start_date
```

And

```
SELECT car_car_id 
FROM invoice_line 
WHERE ('2017-06-12' > start_date AND '2017-06-12' < end_date)
 OR ('2017-06-12' > start_date AND '2017-06-14' < start_date) 
 OR ('2017-06-12' < start_date AND '2017-06-14' > end_date) 
 OR ('2017-06-12' != start_date OR '2017-06-14' != end_date) 
 OR ('2017-06-12' != end_date OR '2017-06-14' != start_date)
```

#### Post Mortem

The issues addressed here could likely have been avoided by using a sub-query in SQL (e.g. `SELECT * FROM car WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT car_car_id FROM invoice_line WHERE ...)`) or a [LEFT JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html) with a condition like `car_car_id IS NULL`.

Comment: Thanks a lot i got it kinda working now, looks like its only picking the last line in the database if i dot 2 records in the time period of 2017-06-12 till 2017-06-14, both with different car_car_id's its only picking the last one for some reason. and if i change the ($ids) to (1,2) it is working with multiple id's so id's is only picking one of the lines

Comment: Alrighty - good. Unfortunately "_if i dot 2 records_" doesn't make much sense to me...can you explain what you mean by that?